# string concatenation not working in jquery- backticks issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function which uses backticks and everything is working fine in all browsers except IE. Did some research and I included the babel-polyfill link `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.4/polyfill.js"></script>`
 but it is not working, I still get the same 'Invalid character' error in IE, So I want to get rid of backticks in my code. I am trying to dynamically populate drop-down lists with dynamic labels and options. Below is the sample code: It renders select label but not the select box.
Commented code is the working code with backticks:
Can some help with the issue.

```
    function appendSelect(obj, select) {
    $.each(obj, function(id, desc) {
        console.log(desc)
            // html = `<div><label class="label">${this.desc+ ':'} </label>
            // <select class="selectClass" id= ${this.id}></select></div>`;
        html = '<div><label class="label">' + this.desc + ':' + '</label><select class="selectClass" id="' + this.id + '></select></div>';
        select.append(html);
        htmlIds.push(document.getElementById(this.id));
    });
    return htmlIds;
}

htmlIds = appendSelect(members, select);
```

Comment: Babel Polyfill shouldn't break other parts of your code; all it does is transpile ES6 to ES5. If it's breaking other parts, *those* are what you should be looking at.

Comment: Sorry, it is not breaking any of my code, but IE still throws me the same error:

Comment: Sorry, it is not breaking any of my code, but IE still throws me the same error for backticks: "Invalid character".
I have included <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.4.4/polyfill.js"></script>
It doesnt work. Any idea?

Comment: Adding a polyfill to the loading page won't help with backticks. Babel needs to transform the JS before it arrives in the browser. It can't tell IE to understand backticks.

Comment: I have used https://babeljs.io/repl to compile my ES6 code to ES5 and it works now in IE browser as well.